# HtmlUnit and jQuery (Drag and Drop)

Tags: java, jquery, drag-and-drop, htmlunit

I don't know if this is supported anywhere in HtmlUnit, but I'm doing some debugging and one of the things I need to do are some drag and drop options that can't be executed through traffic.  I've tried many things similar as showed on this site:

http://mguillem.wordpress.com/2007/08/02/scriptaculous-drag-drop-now-works-for-htmlunit/

However, this didn't move the object at all.  For a bit more info, what I'm exactly trying to:

- I have a table with moveable columns
- I need to be able to drag and drop the columns in various patterns

I'm using eclipse as my IDE.  Any suggestions on what to do?  Does HtmlUnit even support drag-and-drop features?

EDIT: I've been researching how to do this quite some time with no fruitful results.

Comment: Show some code, it makes easier to help. When you execute your code it show some error?

Comment: @brnfd: I would usually show some code, but what I'm doing is extremely similar to what is in the link I provided.  There is no error that generates, it appears that the headless browser thinks it is doing something, when in reality it is doing nothing.